# MySQL to CSV Pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, flask, pythonanywhere

I want to export a mysql database to CSV on pythonanywhere. I opened a mysql console and even tried "select * from ". It shows me the correct output. But when I do "select * from  into outfile 'db.csv';" it shows:  "Access denied for user ''@'%' (using password: YES)".

Answer (score 0):

As per [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html):

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended to enable dumping a
> table to a text file on the server host. To create the resulting file
> on some other host, SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE normally is unsuitable
> because there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the
> server host file system, unless the location of the file on the remote
> host can be accessed using a network-mapped path on the server host
> file system.
>
> Alternatively, if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote
> host, you can use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." >
> file_name to generate the file on that host.

So, to put that another way -- you're connecting to a MySQL server running on a different computer to the one where you're running the MySQL console, and then running a command that is trying to write a file on that other computer, where you don't have privileges to write a file (and would not be able to access it if you did).

Instead, you should start a Bash console, then run a command like this:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p -h yourdatabasehost -e "select * from yourtable" 'yourdatabasename' > db.csv
```

...replacing `yourusername`, `yourdatabasehost`, `yourtable` and `yourdatabasename` appropriately.  The single quotes around `yourdatabasename` are important because on PythonAnywhere, the database name will be something like `yourusername$something`, and the dollar sign will be interpreted by the shell as an environment variable if it is not quoted.